# Append elements of an array to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and also a string. How do I add each element of an array to the string dynamically as the array length might vary?

```js
var array = ["123", "456"];

var str = 'Select * from abc where column_name IN (' + array [0] + ',' + array [1] + ')';

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Use a loop based upon the array length.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array:

```js
var array = ["123", "456", "789"];

var str = 'Select * from abc where column_name IN (' + array.join() + ')';

console.log(str);
```

You can also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of string concatenation:

```js
var array = ["123", "456", "789"];

var str = `Select * from abc where column_name IN (${array.join()})`;

console.log(str);
```